# Why it does matter the order in factorials?

Tags: factorial

So today I was dealing with this factorial:
$$
{m \choose n-1}
$$

This expresses as:

$$
\frac{m!}{(n-1)!(m-n+1)!}
$$
Normally when it's normal numbers and not factorials the signs doesnt matter but here if we change the signs and substitute with numbers will give 2 differents answers, I was wondering why this happen? does the order matters?

Why it has to be 
$$
\frac{m!}{(n-1)!(m-n+1)!}
$$
Instep of 
$$
\frac{m!}{(n+1)!(m-n-1)!}
$$

Comment: "Normally when it's normal numbers and not factorials the signs doesnt matter". What do you mean by that? By all means, the sign matters when you deal with "normal" numbers.

Comment: In general, $\binom nm \ne \binom mn$, if that’s what you’re asking; also, $m^n\ne n^m$

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which "signs"? And which order are you talking about? Can you give an example of different sign and order?

Comment: In rational numbers we have 1, 2, 3, etc... and if we change the signs in n - 1 to n +1 and m - n + 1 to m - n - 1 the answer will be the same, but in factorials no, so I was wondering why the order it matters in this terms on factorials, because if not the answer would be different

Comment: Okay maybe I kinda express my self wrong, I would try to make it easier, why it has to be n - 1 and m - n + 1 instep of, n + 1 and m - n - 1?

Comment: Ah so you're talking only about the denominator of the second expression. Okay ... So where did you get the idea that instead of $n-1$ (which is used in the first expression), you would use $n+1$ ? Of course it gives a different answer, because $n+1 \neq n-1$ ...

Comment: you've not changed all the signs that's why.

Comment: Beacause that is the defination , it's same as asking why arithmetic mean of 4 and 2 is 3 . It how that symbol is defined

Comment: So let's take $m=20$ and $n=4$. The (correct) expression becomes
$$
{20 \choose 3} = \frac{20!}{3! 17!}
$$
This is of course different from
$$
\frac{20!}{5! 15!}
$$
There is absolutely no reason why they should be the same.

Comment: But how do I know that $$
{m \choose n-1}
$$
Expresses as $$
\frac{m!}{(n-1)!(m-n+1)!}
$$ instep of the signs reverse, basically what I'm trying to understand is the signs why it has to start with - and not plus if we subtract it from the main formula of factorials.



Edit: I think I understand it now, basically if the main formula it's expressed as:
$$
\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}
$$
It means that it has to be expressed as 
$$
\frac{m!}{(n-1)!(m-n+1)!}
$$ 
if not I have to change the signs of the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand what you want exactly, but I'll give you some explanation on the binomial coefficient.
${n \choose k}$ is defined as $\frac{n!}{k! \cdot (n-k)!}$.
So let's fill in some numbers. ${5 \choose 3} = \frac{5!}{3! \cdot (5-3)!}$. Now what happens, if i write 3 as 4-1? (that's of the form $n-1$ that you have, so your m now is 5 and your n is 4).
${5 \choose 4-1} = \frac{5!}{(4-1)! \cdot (5-(4-1))!}$ and what is -(4-1)? It's -4+1, so that's where your signs come from.
To summarize, with m = 5 and n = 4 we get:
${5 \choose 4-1} = {m \choose n-1} = \frac{m!}{(n-1)! \cdot (m-(n-1))!} = \frac{5!}{(4-1)! \cdot (5-(4-1))!} = \frac{5!}{3! \cdot (5-3)!} = \frac{5!}{3! \cdot 2!} = {5 \choose 3}$

Comment: Oh, I see now, i'm retarded holy s***, thanks so much I was stuck with this so much time... I was wondering why they start with - and then plus in the 1 and was thinking that was because they say so, and was trying to find out the logic, but now this clarifies it, thank you so much